# Debugging AGS API for Silverlight - returned featureset to graphics layers not drawing

Tags: visual-studio, arcgis-silverlight-api

I have geometries returning from the ArcGIS Server as a featureset from a gp service to the silverlight client.  In debug mode in VS 2010 I see the geometries coming back to the client and I am adding them to a graphics layer that I have defined in the xaml.

I figure I am doing something wrong but I can't figure out how to debug why the graphics aren't showing up in the map.

foreach (Graphic graphic in gpLayer.FeatureSet.Features)
                    {

```
                    ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Geometry.MapPoint point = graphic.Geometry as ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Geometry.MapPoint;
                    point.SpatialReference = MyMap.SpatialReference;
                    {
                        graphic.Symbol = LayoutRoot.Resources["NewPointSymbol"] as ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Symbols.Symbol;
                        graphic.Geometry = point;
                    };

                    //MapPoint geographicPoint = _mercator.ToGeographic(point) as MapPoint;
                    _graphicsLayer.Graphics.Add(graphic);
```

Could this be a scope issue or a projection issue?

Answer (score 1):

It was a projection issue.  Zoomed to the full extent and saw the big green dots off the coast of Africa!

Comment: The process of asking the question is most helpful. Thanks for the forum.. SE!